# using rdbuf()->sputn(...) vs operator<<

Tags: c++, iostream, std

I am looking through some legacy code and found that temporary `std::string` objects are being used liberally throughout the code to convert `const char*` to force the use of :

```
inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & s, const std::string & str)
```

within which `str.c_str()` is used to effect the call to

```
template<class _Traits> inline
    basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL operator<<(
        basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& _Ostr,
        const char *_Val)
```

Weirdly I think this was done because someone created a const char* insertion operator which recursed... Anyway The reason was lost in the dim distant past... I removed it when I noticed exactly what was happening and it all works (AFAIK).

While experimenting with this issue, I redefined `operator<<(std::ostream& , const char*)` to do the following.

```
//
// Disclaimer - experiment!!! not enshrined in code.
//
inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & s, const char * str)
{
   //formerly return s << std::string(str);

   if( str ) s.rdbuf()->sputn( str , strlen(str) );
   return s;
}
```

***Question***
apart from the `strlen` call (preempting some comments) is there much of a downside to bypassing the insertion operator? (I saw some try catch logic in the operator I'm bypassing and I could place this into the operator above perhaps.)

Comment: This functionality already exists (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2). I fail to see the motivation behind this question.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I was curious really - I use insertion operators all the time - the operators add a level of indirection and I hadn't considered doing it this way for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream inserters do **formatted** input, controlled by a double handful of flags in the stream object. Stuffing characters directly into the output buffer bypasses this formatting, so manipulators like `setw` won't affect the output.

Comment: Ok, right - I see what you mean. This stuff is basically dumping unformatted text so I didn't think along those lines. - thx